# Logistic regression & bootstrap

Tags: r, validation, regression, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to run first a logistic regression using `lrm` from the package `RMS`.
My model works fine with `glm` but not with `lrm`.

```
model1 <- lrm( Outcome30Days ~ ISS1 + ISS2 + as.factor(GCSgr)+ 
as.factor(Gender)*as.factor(agegr),data=sub2, x=T, y=T, se.fit=T)
```

If  `ISS1` and `ISS2` are removed  the model runs, but with these 2 variables it won't.
error message:

```
Unable to fit model using “lrm.fit”
```

I need to run it with `lrm`, because the package `validate` using bootstrap works (apparently) only with `lrm`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's simply telling you that _mathematically_ it cannot fit the model as you have specified it. Specifically, it appears to be based on a failure code returned by the underlying Fortran code. Diagnosing the exact problem will require a detailed understanding of both your data and the exact mathematical procedure used to fit the model.

Comment: Thanks Joran, if it was incorrect how come the model works with glm? Something is puzzling about lrm.

Comment: I think I made it work by using penalty =5, below 5 it doesn't work.

Comment: The model would look like this:

Comment: model1 <- lrm( Outcome30Days ~ ISS1 + ISS2 + as.factor(GCSgr)+ 
as.factor(Gender)*as.factor(agegr),data=sub2, x=T, y=T, se.fit=T, penalty=5)

Answer (score 1):

lrm has a lower tolerance for correlation among independent variables than glm. If your model runs with glm and runs with lrm when you remove some variables this is probably the issue. Luckily, you can adjust the tolerance with the tol argument. By default tol=1e-7. Try changing it to tol=1e-9. The code would look like this:

```
model1 <- lrm( Outcome30Days ~ ISS1 + ISS2 + as.factor(GCSgr)+ 
as.factor(Gender)*as.factor(agegr),data=sub2, x=T, y=T, se.fit=T, tol=1e-9)
```

This is better than messing with the penalty because changing the penalty will change your log-likelihood and could affect your results.

Comment: Another option is to increase the maximum number of iterations with the `maxit=` option -- the default in `lrm.fit()` sitting under `lrm()` is 12 iterations, while the default in `glm.fit()` is 25, according to the help files.